# pyspark: count number of consecutive ones/zeros and change them if streak is to short / to long

Tags: dataframe, search, replace, pyspark

i work with a large pyspark dataframe on a cluster and need to write a function that:

1. finds rows of consecutive zeros in a specific column and, if that streak is shorter than 300 rows, change them all to 1 and
2. then finds periods of consecutive ones in that column and, if that streak of ones is shorter than 1800 rows, set them all to 0.

Every row has a unique timestamp i can sort them by.

is there a way to make that happen?

Comment: In order to make people understand quickly , it's always good to share the input and output data looks like..

Comment: Look into windowing functions to achieve this. Here's an example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54445961/pyspark-calculate-streak-of-consecutive-observations

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can **follow this example** where I searched for strikes of less than 3 zeros and converted them to ones:

```
column = 'data'
date_column = 'timestamp'
min_consecutive_rows = 3
search_num = 0
set_to = 1

df = df.withColumn('binary', F.when(col(column)==search_num, 1).otherwise(0))\
.withColumn('start_streak', F.when(col('binary') != F.lead('binary', -1).over(w), 1).otherwise(0))\
.withColumn('streak_id', F.sum('start_streak').over(Window.orderBy(date_column)))\
.withColumn("streak_counter", F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("streak_id").orderBy(date_column)))\
.withColumn('max_streak_counter', F.max('streak_counter').over(Window.partitionBy("streak_id")))\
.withColumn(column, F.when((col('binary')==1) & (col('max_streak_counter') < min_consecutive_rows), set_to).otherwise(col(column)))
```

Suppose your data column is called *data* and your date column is called *timestamp*.

**The performed steps are the following:**

1. *binary* column is used to search only streaks of the desired *search_num* number. It allows your data to have other numbers rather than only zeros and ones, still searching only streaks of zeros in this case.
2. *start_streak* tell us which rows are the start of a new streak
3. *streak_id* creates a unique ID for each streak
4. *streak_counter* counts the elements on each streak
5. *max_streak_counter* tell us the maximum counter of elements for each streak_id
6. Finally *data_output* converts the numbers only if the streak is less than *min_consecutive_rows* parameter and it is composed by the requested *search_num* numbers (zeros in this case)

Here an example with all the intermediate columns:

```
|           timestamp|data|binary|start_streak|streak_id|streak_counter|max_streak_counter|data_output|
+--------------------+----+------+------------+---------+--------------+------------------+-----------+
|2020-11-11 15:52:...|   1|     0|           0|        0|             1|                 5|          1|
|2020-11-12 15:52:...|   2|     0|           0|        0|             2|                 5|          2|
|2020-11-13 15:52:...|   3|     0|           0|        0|             3|                 5|          3|
|2020-11-14 15:52:...|   4|     0|           0|        0|             4|                 5|          4|
|2020-11-15 15:52:...|   1|     0|           0|        0|             5|                 5|          1|
|2020-11-16 15:52:...|   0|     1|           1|        1|             1|                 2|          1|
|2020-11-17 15:52:...|   0|     1|           0|        1|             2|                 2|          1|
|2020-11-18 15:52:...|   1|     0|           1|        2|             1|                 1|          1|
|2020-11-19 15:52:...|   0|     1|           1|        3|             1|                 4|          0|
|2020-11-20 15:52:...|   0|     1|           0|        3|             2|                 4|          0|
|2020-11-21 15:52:...|   0|     1|           0|        3|             3|                 4|          0|
|2020-11-22 15:52:...|   0|     1|           0|        3|             4|                 4|          0|
+--------------------+----+------+------------+---------+--------------+------------------+-----------+
```

**For the second bullet point** just change: *column* to 'data_output', *min_consecutive_rows* to 1800, *search_num* to 1, *set_to* parameter to 0 and repeat the code above.

For more details about the streak calcuation please visit [this post](https://joshdevlin.com/blog/calculate-streaks-in-pandas/) that does a similar logic in pandas.